# Hive queries with dates

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hiveql, hive-query

I have a little problem, I would like to filter a date with hive query but the output is empty. My column is string type

I tried this :

```
select * from my_table 
where to_date(date) < to_date('01/08/19 00:00:00')
```

The format of my column date is `01/08/19 18:00:00`

Comment: to_date function returns a string. Is this what you intended? In such a case you are trying to compare two strings. If you want to do date comparisons (as in the arithmetic sense), you may want to try unix_timestamp function, instead. It will give you a number and you can compare two numbers and decide which one is bigger and which one is smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in this format `'01/08/19 00:00:00'` are not in comparable format because in such format `'02/08/19 00:00:00'` is greater than `'01/08/20 00:00:00'`.

Use `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime` to convert to the comparable format (`'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`), then compare with date in the same format.

```
select * from my_table 
where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') < '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
```